# Access Report Prompt to Populate a Textbox and use as query criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I am building a report in Access where I am asking the user to input the Order Number before a report opens.
 The order number is meant to populate a *textbox* and act as a criteria for two queries (the queries are used for sub-reports).

So far I have been trying to solve this without **vba**. I use InputBox as the Control Source for the TextBox and refer to the value of the textbox in the query criteria.

This works just fine, however, the user is asked to input the order number twice (two identical popups, the first one fires off the queries, the second populates the textbox).

Is there any way to avoid the double prompt?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you not create a Form and collect the number for the report there?

Comment: That being a perfect solution, it requires for me to change the input scenario which I can't do...

Comment: Do you mean you do not want to change the input box to a form? Or am I not following what you mean?

Comment: I don't want to have a separate form that would fetch the ID for the report. I am thinking of generating a pop-up form on the fly - but not sure how to implement it just yet...

Comment: The only way I could think is create a Form that mimics an InputBox and then you can, set its visibility to False so the Query can base its criteria on the form. I am not sure if creating and disposing a Form during runtime is the best way ! I could be wrong.

Comment: @Knodel: Not sure why you want to avoid VBA especially in your case. Ideally for performance reasons, Query is generated first then the report is opened not the other way. if you really don't want to use vba why not use datamacro there you can save userinput in a variable and open the report with filter... Just thoughts!!

Comment: @Krish KM: Hey! I'm not avoiding it at all, just trying to make it as straighforward and efficient as possible :)

Comment: @Knodel: !Efficient! afaik, developers are roasted and fried to get efficiency in usability :D
back to your question: you can write simple code on "On Open" event showing form and taking the input and construct the query and assign it to me.recordsource.. is that efficient? :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the InputBox into the Report Open event, and use the return value to populate the field on the report. Then link the subreports to the main report (Master/Child).